# jquery ui auto complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was using Jquery ui auto-complete with version 1.8.2 and later i shifted to 1.8.11. I started having problems.

[image: auto complete in jquery 1.8.2]

1.8.2

[image: auto complete in jquery 1.8.11]

1.8.11

```
$('#term').autocomplete({
        minLength    : 4,
        source        : rootPath+'/search',
        select: function(event, ui) 
        {
            window.location =  ui.item.url;
        }
    });
```

1. How can i fix it
2. and Where can in http://jqueryui.com/ i can get 1.8.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/:

> The label is always treated as text,
>   if you want the label to be treated as
>   html you can use Scott González' html
>   extension.

And the aforementioned extension is located here: https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js.

Comment: any other way to acieve. why is it working in 1.8.2 and not 1.8.11

Comment: It was removed in 1.8.4, see http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8.4. Also, considering the documentation says to do that, I'm pretty sure there's no other way to do it in 1.8.11.  See http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5275 for the related ticket.

Answer (score 2):

For you to render a custom HTML element in Auto Complete you need to use ._renderItem.

Once you render custom data then you can capture that using select method and process it the way you want.

Use following link to learn  abour custom data formatting in jquery auto-complete

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data